# Debugging crash from Device not connected to Xcode 7 - Symbolicate

Tags: ios, xcode7, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

Before I explain let me just say I have looked all over and tried many many ways of symbolicating the crash log.

MY ISSUE: When my app (on my iPhone) is ran from Xcode, the app never crashes. When my app is ran on my phone, and not connected to my computer at all, it crashes in the same spot every-time.

MY SYMBOLICATE ISSUE: I have retrieved the crash file from my phone, i've got the .dSYM file from the archived build and the UUID's don't match up, so I can't symbolicate the crash and find the line of code that's causing the problem.

MY GOAL: To resolve this error. It seems the best way to do it is by the Symbolicate command, but maybe there is something new with Xcode 7 that makes symbolicating a crash file from a device much easier?

Hope this is clear. Thanks so much!

Comment: Start by having the dSYM file that matches the installed app.

Comment: Do I get that from the archived build in Xcode? Or do I get that from my device?

Comment: If you installed an archived build then yes, get the dSYM from the same archive.

Comment: No I didn't, I just built and ran from Xcode. I tried getting the dSYM from the current project, not the archived build, and still got the same UUID info.